# Unable to remove heteroscadasticity

Tags: r, multiple-regression, heteroscedasticity

This is my model:

```
lm(PCTUI~year+statefips+factor_agecat+factor_sexcat+factor_racecat+factor_iprcat, data = train)
```

I have factorized the categorical variable. Tried using `log`, `lmrobust` or `rlm`. Also tried `boxCox` but still my residual vs fitted graph looks like the image below:
[image]

Can anybody help me removing the heteroscadasticity?

Comment: What is `PCTUI`?

Comment: Percentage uninsured

Comment: Maybe the data just are heterogeneous. In that case you should use a model that could accommodate that instead of trying to "fix" it.

Comment: I do not see much evidence of heteroscedasticity--the huge numbers of overplotted points obscure almost all relevant information about it.  Could you therefore explain why you think there is heteroscedasticity in amounts that matter for your analysis?

Comment: I do see a little evidence of heteroscedasticity maybe as it seems the variability tends to shrink for larger fitted value, but it'd difficulty to say as @whuber has said because of the huge number of overplotted points obscures must of the information.  Given that your data is a percentage, I'd recommend taking a look at the transformation $y^{\prime}=2 arcsin \sqrt{y}$ (of course  you'll need to be sure your $y$ are set as proportions instead of in percent (i.e. whole numbers).   Also, have you considered carrying out a formal test for heteroscedasticity?

Comment: @whuber: What I see is evidence that this model tends to over-predict - notice how most of the residuals are falling below the horizontal line going through zero. (See http://www.thejuliagroup.com/blog/?p=1523 for an explanation of over- and under- prediction.) I think this is a more serious concern than heteroscedasticity, which usually assumes that the model has no systematic tendency to either over-predict or under-predict, as it indicates the model specification may need more care - not just the transformation of the outcome variable, but what predictors get included in the model.

Comment: @Isabella: That could also be an artifact of the overplotting---else how coud the residuals sum to zero?

Comment: Its because when I am doing the bptest the p-valIts because when I am doing the bptest the p-value is coming as 2.2e-16ue is coming as 2.2e-16

Comment: Can you give more context? Or at least plot the residuals with transparent points or otherwise so overplottong do not distort? It could be a problem that your response variable is bounded, maybe try beta regression or logit transform your response ...